# Asp.net core 2 - 401 error with bearer token

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, bearer-token

I'm not able to access protected method with Authorized with a token generated by Asp.net Core.

**The configuration :**

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                cfg.SaveToken = true;
                cfg.Audience = Configuration["Tokens:Issuer"];
                cfg.ClaimsIssuer = Configuration["Tokens:Issuer"];
                cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["Tokens:Issuer"],
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["Tokens:Issuer"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Tokens:Key"]))
                };
```

**The token generated :**

```
var claims = new[] {
                new Claim (JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, model.Email),
                new Claim (JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid ().ToString()),
            };

            //_config
            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Tokens:Key"]));
            var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
            var expiration = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7);
            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_config["Tokens:Issuer"],
                _config["Tokens:Issuer"],
                claims,
                expires: expiration,
                signingCredentials: creds);

            return new TokenModel()
            {
                Token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
                Expiration = expiration,
                UserFirstName = model.FirstName,
                UserLastName = model.LastName
            };
```

After the generation I get this kind of token :

```
{
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ0ZWl4ZWlyYXBlcnNvQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImp0aSI6IjVmNTk3OGVkLWRlZjAtNDM3Yi1hOThhLTg3ZWU4YTQ3MmZlNCIsImV4cCI6MTUxODg2ODYxOCwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo1MDAwIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo1MDAwIn0.1fHXr8jtuZ8PTJmJPBKQIqiOk_c-bCQ6KRyFLLJkU5s",
    "expiration": "2018-02-17T11:56:58.683076Z",
    "userFirstName": null,
    "userLastName": null
}
```

I can add or not the autorization in my HTTP headers in Postman, I receive an **"Unauthorized Exception - 401"**

I already check some other **Stack** post and **GitHub** Post, It seems my configuration it's ok.

If needed I can add the configuration file.

Thanks.

**Edit 1 :**

Here the screen of the header in postman :

[image]

Comment: how is your authorization header looking?

Comment: @DotNetDev picture added :)

Comment: Are you sure the same security algorithm (HMACSHA256) is being used to validate the token?  You don't specify it in your `.AddJwtBearer` options so it will use the default which may not be the same algorithm.

Comment: have you checked the token on jwt.io?

Comment: Ok, i will check.

Comment: Ok So i remove some extra configuration and it's works.... thnks guys

Comment: @OrcusZ So my configuration in startup.cs and my token generation is identical to what you have above. Can you please tell me which extra configs did you remove?

Comment: @OrcusZ Nevermind, I got it :) Just removed all the options and kept the absolute min which is the issuersigningkey, validissuer and validaudience.

Answer (score 42):

I'm unsure if you're facing the same issue, but I'm running an ASP.NET Core project with code looking similar to yours.

I encountered `401` responses when including a bearer token provided by the API's login, but this was fixed by calling `app.UseAuthentication()` as the **first** method in `Configure()`. My code changed from this...

```
app.UseMvc();
app.UseAuthentication();
```

To this...

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseMvc();
```

Comment: You are saver! I just lost couple hours figuring why it doesn't work and it was just order of calls!

Comment: If i could give you 10000 points I would. This is exactly my issue.

Comment: You are a lifesaver. This small change cost me two days. Kudos!

Answer (score 7):

Your code looks OK. The most possible root cause of the problem is that you have not added authentication middleware to your application. `AddAuthentication` extension call for `IServiceCollection` just registers all required services, but it does not add authentication middleware to HTTP request pipeline.

To fix the problem add following call in `Startup.Configure()` method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseAuthentication();

    // ...
}
```

I was able to reproduce the problem with your code, and calling `app.UseAuthentication()` fixes the issue.

Comment: Hm, then I can't reproduce your problem. I've copy/pasted your code and authentication works fine if `app.UseAuthentication()` is called.

Comment: humm... I think I did not tell it, but i'm running this code in a macOS system, I don't know if this can be the source of the problem

Comment: Do you have a chance to launch it on Windows? It will help a lot to narrow the possible root causes.

Comment: Yes. I will did it and back when I have tested it correctly in a windows system :)

Comment: @OrcusZ Anychance you every find the issue? I'm in the exact same situation right now.

Comment: @hjavaher it was an configuration mistake for me. Post a new issue I will have a look